for loop not entered in python
I have the following py function that starting from a CSV file should create instances of a class that i defined somewhere above in the code. My problem is that it doesn't run the for loop after the if nErr == 0. It is only printing "Here I am".
def checkCSV_creaIstanze(fileCSV, istanze):              # la  funzione controlla i campi del CSV - se è tutto ok crea le istanze
  with open(fileCSV, newline='') as file_csv:
    lettore_csv = csv.reader(file_csv, delimiter=';')
    next(lettore_csv)   # salto header csv
    nErr = 0
    for riga in lettore_csv:
      for i in range(0,7):
        if riga[i] == '':
          print(f'riga {lettore_csv.line_num-1} - colonna {i+1}: dato assente')
          nErr += 1
        if i == 1:
          if len(riga[i]) != 11:
            print(f'riga {lettore_csv.line_num-1} {riga[0]} - codice fiscale non coerente: {riga[i]}')
            nErr += 1
        if i == 2:
          if len(riga[i]) != 2:
            print(f'riga {lettore_csv.line_num-1} {riga[0]} - codice stato non coerente: {riga[i]}')
            nErr += 1
    if nErr == 0:
      print('here I am')
      for riga in lettore_csv:
        print('dati coerenti\ncreo istanze di classe...')
        Sgr = SGR(riga[0], riga[1], riga[2], riga[3], riga[4], riga[5], riga[6], riga[7], riga[8])
        istanze.append(Sgr)
      # print('istanze cerate')
    else:
      print('si è verificato un problema')
  return istanze

I tried to change indentations but It seems correct to me. Do you have any idea?
Many thanks in advance

Once the first for loop stops, the csv file will be exhausted and will not run again.

You've already processed the csv stream in the previous for loop so theres no more lines left to iterate over, store the data in some sort of collection and iterate over that
